# navbar displaying content vertically

Tags: angular, navbar, angular8

I'm new to Angular. I have started building an app and this is my code for navbar. The navbar is not displaying as expected and contents are printed vertically.

My header.component.html looks like this:-

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Shopping List</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Fetch Data</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

this is my webpage:-

Recipe Book
Recipes
Shopping List

Manage
Save Data
Fetch Data

All these are printed as links vertically(not able to show it here) that is fine but where is the horizontal navbar?

Comment: Replicate your issue on https://stackblitz.com/ and update your question. We need to see what you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Install bootstrap Correctly and in your angular .json add

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ]
```

and see [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czhzj6) as per your requirements

Comment: Yeah actually I added this in test and not build section of angular.json file. also I had put 2 dots before( ../node_modules).after removing them and restarting the server it worked!!! thanks